# Gurnt: shell task on git bash does recognize the space in path

Tags: node.js, path, gruntjs, command-prompt, git-bash

In my grunt file I have a task as follow:

```
 shell: {
        test: {
            command: [
                process.argv[0] + ' node_modules/abc/bin/abc-node',
```

The `process.argv[0] is c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`
when I run the task on command prompt or intellij it is fine but when I run it in Git Bash I get the following error:

```
Warning: Command failed: 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or                 
external command,
operable program or batch file.
Use --force to continue.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
command: [
    'node node_modules/abc/bin/abc-node'
```